# No "compile with" option when creating a new android application?

Tags: android, eclipse-indigo

[image][image]

No "compile with" option when creating a new android application?

Software : Eclipse IDE for Java Developers 
           Version: Indigo Service Release 2
           Build id: 20120216-1857

[image]

Comment: Set your SDK home once again in your Android Preferences on Eclipse.

Comment: sorry to ask but how to do it?

Comment: Its OK,Go to Window -> Preferences, click on Android and set SDK location to directory. (for example /home/user/AndroidSDK) and click on Apply.

Comment: i have uploaded a screen shot. this is what we get. my android sdk manager is not working.

Comment: same problem dude :(

Comment: Goto windows sdk manager , let it load ,Make sure you have at least one "SDK Platform" as "Installed" , if you cannot open sdk manager , Bst option , remove everything , install again , this is ecipse and sometimes this happens :)

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been often occurred by Many People.
Solution is

> **Update ADT plugin and then SDK tools and after when you will try to create a new project, the error will not occur**

- Eclipse--> Help-->Install New Software-->What is already installed?
- Then, Select "Android DDMS, Andoid Devlopment Tools,Android Hierarcy Viewer, Android native Development Tools, Android Traceview, Tracer for OpenGL ES" and click Uninstall.
- After all this step, try Add link (https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/) and name is ADT Plugin. This link will get the latest ADT Plugin. In this way you reinstall the ADT.

Eclipse will restart and hopefully everything should work fine for you.